# React - Set default attribute while using map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I want to render tabs that I stored in an array and set the first tab in the array as default.

Not using an array, it would look kind of like this:

```
<Tab
   name={"first tab"}
   default
/>
<Tab
   name={"second tab"}
/>
```

But now since I'm using an array and mapping through it, I'm wondering how i can set the default attribute for the first tab.

This is how the array looks like:

```
  const tabs = [
{
  name: "first tab",
  
},
{
  name: "second tab",
}]
```

This is my map function:

```
    {tabs.map(tab => (
      <Tab
        name={tab.name} />
    )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` passes your callback the index of the entry as the second argument, so:

```
{tabs.map((tab, index) => (
    <Tab
        key={tab.name}
        name={tab.name}
        default={index === 0}
    />
)}
```

Note I've also added a [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), since you need that whenever you give an array to React.

Comment: Another link for more information about keys: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28329382/218196

Answer (score 2):

The *second* argument to the callback you pass to `map` is the index.

The first item will have an index of `0` (which is false).

So capture that and then you can just: `default={!index}`

Answer (score 1):

Use the array index, the default tab would be index 0, or all truthy indices would ***not*** be default.

```
{tabs.map((tab, i) => (
  <Tab
    key={tab.name}
    default={!i}
    name={tab.name} />
)}
```